# How to extract Image urls with formula and add in different columns in Microsoft Sheet and Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, xlsx

I have this product feed from website, and in **imageUrlStr** column there are three images URL, I have added three more columns like Image1, Image2 and Image3.

imageUrlStr value

```
https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/200/200/l48s9zk0/water-geyser/g/o/i/2022-finesse-2000-ao-smith-10-original-imagf5zqzevs48p5.jpeg?q=90;https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/400/400/l48s9zk0/water-geyser/g/o/i/2022-finesse-2000-ao-smith-10-original-imagf5zqzevs48p5.jpeg?q=90;https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/800/800/l48s9zk0/water-geyser/g/o/i/2022-finesse-2000-ao-smith-10-original-imagf5zqzevs48p5.jpeg?q=90
```

I have tried this `=LEFTB(D2,100)` but as the length of the url is different this solution does not works.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kLzW8_pg_wUiLg3rzhUX5fZfXlwIANm2r1mi9cvcrCk/edit?usp=sharing

You can edit and view product feed sheet from above url.

How can I retrieve image url as in different columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMAGE(IFERROR(SPLIT(D2:D; ";"))))
```

[image]

or just url would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(D2:D; ";")))
```

or to get only first link:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(D2:D; ";"));;1)
```

Comment: I think its working, 
Is there any way to show only url instead of Image in cell?

Comment: @WasimShaikh use 2nd formula

Comment: Thanks its working in Google Sheet, If possible could you please share the formula for MS Excel , This only works in Google Sheet.

Comment: @WasimShaikh yes, this is for google sheets. unfortunately, I am not familiar with MS Excel syntax structure